# Errors encountered in 10.3.3 of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial

Tags: railstutorial.org

I ran into the following errors when running my RSpec tests:

**Failures:**

```
1) Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x007f89628593f8>:0x007f895fcdcd38>
 # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___2268788413810348528_70113969385200'
 # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__501962788019734978_70114020097480'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:108:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x007f89628593f8>:0x007f895ff8c3a8>
 # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___2268788413810348528_70113969385200'
 # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__501962788019734978_70114020097480'
 # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information error messages 
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x007f89628593f8>:0x007f8962b99798>
 # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___2268788413810348528_70113969385200'
 # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__501962788019734978_70114020097480'
 # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 4) Micropost pages micropost creation with valid information should create a micropost
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x007f89628593f8>:0x007f895de6c3a8>
 # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___2268788413810348528_70113969385200'
 # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__501962788019734978_70114020097480'
 # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) Static pages for signed-in users should render the user's feed
 Failure/Error: visit root_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x007f89628593f8>:0x007f895dd16f80>
 # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___2268788413810348528_70113969385200'
 # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__501962788019734978_70114020097480'
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec
```

**Code:**

The code for authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }



      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
          end
        end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "in the Microposts controller" do

      describe "submitting to the create action" do
        before { post microposts_path }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
      end

      describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
        before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end

    describe "as non-admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before { sign_in non_admin }

      describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
        before { delete user_path(user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The code for _feed.html.erb**

```
    <li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
```

The code for _feed_item.html.erb

```
    <li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Please let me know if there are additional files I should include. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for your **_feed.html.erb** and **_feed_item.html.erb**?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti, thanks for comment. I just added the two files you mentioned.

Comment: Compare your **_feed.html.erb** to [the tutorial's](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb).  You may need to go back and revise a few files :-)

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  I've moved the info into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your **_feed.html.erb** and **_feed_item.html.erb** files: at the moment, you're referencing `feed_item` without having defined it anywhere.

Refer to the equivalent files in Rails Tutorial: [**_feed.html.erb**](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb), [**_feed_item.html.erb**](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb).